# Too much boiler plate code switch statement - iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, switch-statement, uilabel, boilerplate

I have a switch statement which will add texts to 11 UILabels appropriately. However, its getting a bit long now and there is far too much copies of the same code. How can I further improve it? Could I maybe make an array of labels and then just access them via a for loop??

Here is code switch statement:

```
switch ([number_sorted count]) {

            case 1:
                label_1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[0] integerValue]];
                break;

            case 2:
                label_1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[0] integerValue]];
                label_2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[1] integerValue]];
                break;

            case 3:
                label_1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[0] integerValue]];
                label_2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[1] integerValue]];
                label_3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[2] integerValue]];
                break;

            case 4:
                label_1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[0] integerValue]];
                label_2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[1] integerValue]];
                label_3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[2] integerValue]];
                label_4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[3] integerValue]];
                break;

            case 5:
                label_1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[0] integerValue]];
                label_2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[1] integerValue]];
                label_3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[2] integerValue]];
                label_4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[3] integerValue]];
                label_5.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[4] integerValue]];
                break;

            case 6:
                label_1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[0] integerValue]];
                label_2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[1] integerValue]];
                label_3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[2] integerValue]];
                label_4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[3] integerValue]];
                label_5.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[4] integerValue]];
                label_6.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[5] integerValue]];
                break;

            case 7:
                label_1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[0] integerValue]];
                label_2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[1] integerValue]];
                label_3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[2] integerValue]];
                label_4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[3] integerValue]];
                label_5.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[4] integerValue]];
                label_6.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[5] integerValue]];
                label_7.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[6] integerValue]];
                break;

            case 8:
                label_1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[0] integerValue]];
                label_2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[1] integerValue]];
                label_3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[2] integerValue]];
                label_4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[3] integerValue]];
                label_5.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[4] integerValue]];
                label_6.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[5] integerValue]];
                label_7.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[6] integerValue]];
                label_8.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[7] integerValue]];
                break;

            case 9:
                label_1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[0] integerValue]];
                label_2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[1] integerValue]];
                label_3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[2] integerValue]];
                label_4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[3] integerValue]];
                label_5.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[4] integerValue]];
                label_6.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[5] integerValue]];
                label_7.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[6] integerValue]];
                label_8.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[7] integerValue]];
                label_9.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[8] integerValue]];
                break;

            case 10:
                label_1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[0] integerValue]];
                label_2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[1] integerValue]];
                label_3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[2] integerValue]];
                label_4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[3] integerValue]];
                label_5.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[4] integerValue]];
                label_6.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[5] integerValue]];
                label_7.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[6] integerValue]];
                label_8.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[7] integerValue]];
                label_9.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[8] integerValue]];
                label_10.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[9] integerValue]];
                break;

            case 11:
                label_1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[0] integerValue]];
                label_2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[1] integerValue]];
                label_3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[2] integerValue]];
                label_4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[3] integerValue]];
                label_5.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[4] integerValue]];
                label_6.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[5] integerValue]];
                label_7.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[6] integerValue]];
                label_8.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[7] integerValue]];
                label_9.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[8] integerValue]];
                label_10.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[9] integerValue]];
                label_11.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[10] integerValue]];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
```

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: Instead of having 11 ivars for the labels, use an array of labels. Then the code can be one single tiny loop.

Comment: Another solution would be to look up the labels dynamically using objc_... runtime functions such as by creating the selector name for the label and then invoking objc_msgSend(). No need to change their declarations that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to use the "fall through" property of switch statements

```
switch ([number_sorted count]) {
    case 11:
        label_11.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[10] integerValue]];
    case 10:
        label_10.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[9] integerValue]];
    case 9:
        label_9.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[8] integerValue]];
    case 8:
        label_8.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[7] integerValue]];
    case 7:
        label_7.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[6] integerValue]];
    case 6:
        label_6.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[5] integerValue]];
    case 5:
        label_5.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[4] integerValue]];
    case 4:
        label_4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[3] integerValue]];
    case 3:
        label_3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[2] integerValue]];
    case 2:
        label_2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[1] integerValue]];
    case 1:
        label_1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[number_sorted[0] integerValue]];
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. Quite clever.

Comment: Don't discount @Rob's concept, it's applicability is very general

Comment: Robs solution seems good but it is based on IB tags... I think Daij-Djan solution is best, but I can't get it to work yet.

Comment: is this method safe? Because (for obvious reasons) you have left out the break statements. Hopefully this won't lead to any unexpected exceptions?

Comment: It a reasonably standard construction, the switch statement was designed to support use without a break statement. We used to see this a lot more programming in "C".

Comment: The code in this answer is safe. Typically it's a bug when the `break` is missing but in a situation like this, it is what you actually want. As a convention, I always add a comment in place of the missing `break` clarifying that is really shouldn't be there.

Comment: I'll also add that while this answer is slick, it's still the wrong solution. It's fragile and prone to bugs due to simply typos. It also doesn't scale well. You really should use "loop" solution. It's far less buggy, more scalable, and far easier to read and write.

Comment: I REALLY dislike it. It still duplicates A LOT of code for no reason. The concept is good but in this case i'd say it is not appropriate

Comment: Unfortunately I have to agree with DD and M.  This ... sucks. the entire, fundamental nature of programming is to eliminate repetition by using higher-level concepts.  It's admirable for super to understand that in this particular programming language one can fall-through a switch body, but that's the only pedagogic quality.  This is a great opportunity for the OP to advance on collections, making controls in code, or more. (AND still nobody is concerned about the blank items! heh)

Answer (score 2):

Just put your UILabel's in an NSArray. Then you can iterate over the array. In Interface Builder, you can add a bunch of elements to an `IBOutletCollection`, which is convenient (just drag multiple things together, like creating an `IBOutlet`, and it'll offer to make an `IBOutletCollection`).

Just note that `IBOutletCollection` makes no promises on order. So you may need to add a `tag` in IB to keep track of them. I often sort my collection by `tag` in `viewDidLoad`.

If you build this system programmatically, you can just put them in the array to start with.

Sometimes keeping track of `tag` is still too much of a pain, so I cheat a bit. I just use `subviews` to walk all the views and find my labels. Then I sort them by y-origin and stick them in an array. That of course is a bit fragile and requires a lot of special knowledge about your view, but a view controller is expected to have that knowledge. I occasionally use this technique to create a hybrid IB/programmatic interface, which lets me lay everything out in IB, but then wire everything up (actions, font selection, etc) in code. I especially do that when there are a lot of almost identical UI elements.

Answer (score 2):

use two arrays: 1. for all labels, 2. for the counts.
you already have the 2. part so:

First, in your class have an `NSArray *_labels`. 
Then in your viewDidLoad do `_labels = @[label1, label2, label3];`

then for the switch

```
for(int i = 0; i < number_sorted.count; i++) {
    ((UILabel*)_labels[i]).text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [number_sorted[i] integerValue]];
}
```

Comment: I get the error, property 'text' not found on object of type 'id'.

Comment: @Daij-Djan I am seeing a lit of variables and ivars with a leading underscore "_" in SO. I understand that properties generate ivars with a leading underscore but why access them this way? Usually if there is a property the value should be accessed via the getter/setter like self.labels. Is there some bias against using properties? Is there some instructer/class or tutorial that is recommending this?

Comment: oh my bad @Supertecnoboff don't use the . syntax or cast. I 'fixed' the code

Comment: @zaph yes. I never spoke about making a property though :) _I_ don't use properties for private stuff.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Just wondering why not, is there some instruction not to? I am seeing a lot of examples of this lately on SO.

Comment: no ... I guess it is a matter of style and to be honest I guess one should use properties for everything a tad more complex.

Comment: direct vars are just so damned convenient :D

Comment: you can put them in the m file even .. in the implementation that is --> `@implementation MyClass { id _myVar; } ... @end`